# Entity framework - Conditionally query related entities with type converting

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two class:

```
public abstract class Conversation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class PrivateConversation : Conversation
{
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

In DbContext, there are DbSets:

```cs
public DbSet<Conversation> Conversations { get; set; }
public DbSet<PrivateConversation> PrivateConversations { get; set; }
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Which generates two tables: `Conversations` and `Users`.

> PrivateConversations are saved in table `Conversations`

Now an error occurred with query:

```
// For some reason, I can only query `db.Conversations`, can not access `db.PrivateConversations`
var conversations = db.Conversations
  .Include(t => (t as PrivateConversation).Users)
  .Where(t => t is PrivateConversation)
  .Where(t => (t as PrivateConversation).Users.Any())
  .ToList();
```

Told me that in `Users.Any()`, `Users` is null.

I am very confused. How can I query all private conversations with user in it?

#### Additional info:

packages I usesd:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLServer" Version="2.2.6" />
```

runtime: .NET Core 2.2

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: What is the EF Core version?

Comment: @IvanStoev Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I have added the context info in the question part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any documentation regarding this.

According to [Include on derived types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#include-on-derived-types) one can use either `as` operator or explict cast. And indeed both work for `Include`. But in standard LINQ operators the `as` operator is causing client evaluation and the exception in question - client evaluation occurs at a time the navigation properties are not loaded yet (despite the `Include`). One more reason for removing client evaluation in 3.0.

Back to your issue. The solution is to use explicit cast:

```
.Where(t => ((PrivateConversation)t).Users.Any())
```

which correctly translates to SQL, hence has no NRE issues at all.